# How to run j2me project on android device

Tags: android, java-me

I am converting a j2me project to run an android device. for this purpose  both the jad and jar file to be converted by the following url and get the apk file.

http://www.netmite.com/android/srv/2.0/getapk.php

After that install the j2me runner apk in my device. and running the converted apk file. it is running well but facing a problem to enter any input data.

**when enter any input data the android keypad could not open directly on my device. A T9 menu is open on my application right menu option. To click on T9 menu a editor is open to enter the input data.**

Comment: Your app is basically run and managed by a translation layer that translate J2ME APIs into Android ones, if you want to change the behavior, you probably have to get the original J2ME-->Android translation author to make the changes.

Comment: please provide any document tutorial or link to solve my problem

Comment: I've experimented a lot with running J2ME on Android, and in my opinion that best option/solution is PhoneME: http://davy.preuveneers.be/phoneme/?q=node/10